How do I check if a meeting has already been created before joining it with the AWS Chime SDK?
I am building a video conferencing application using React Native and I have the basic Chime demo set up and working properly. However, I only want a particular set of users to be able to create meetings and the rest should only be able to join existing meetings. Instead of all users being able to create and start meetings, I want some users to be able to check and see if a meeting with a given meetingId is already in progress and then be able to join but if the meeting doesn't already exist, do nothing or show a "The meeting hasn't started yet." message.
I see that there is a way to get meeting info using ChimeSDKMeetingsClient() along with GetMeetingCommand() but there isn't a lot of information on what sort of config I need to pass into ChimeSDKMeetingsClient. I pass the region like this:
      const client = new ChimeSDKMeetingsClient({ region: "MY_REGION" });
      const input = {
        MeetingId: MY_MEETING_ID,
      };
      const command = new GetMeetingCommand(input);
      const response = await client.send(command);

and get the following error in my catch block:
"Credential is missing"
I currently am using Cognito for authentication and AWS Identity Pools for authorization. Do I need to be passing in accessToken or idToken as part of the config along with the region? I have been searching for hours and can't find a lot of documentation on this.

Yes, you're correct. The ChimeSDKMeetingsClient requires AWS credentials to make requests. Since you're using Cognito for authentication, you can use the AWS SDK for JavaScript to get the credentials from the logged-in user and pass them to the ChimeSDKMeetingsClient.
Here's a step-by-step:

Import the necessary AWS SDK and Amazon Chime SDK modules.
Get the current authenticated user from Cognito.
Get the AWS credentials from the authenticated user.
Pass these credentials to the ChimeSDKMeetingsClient.
Use the GetMeetingCommand to check if a meeting exists.

Example:
import { ChimeSDKMeetingsClient, GetMeetingCommand } from "@aws-sdk/client-chime-sdk-meetings";
import { CognitoIdentityClient, GetIdCommand, GetCredentialsForIdentityCommand } from "@aws-sdk/client-cognito-identity";
import { fromCognitoIdentityPool } from "@aws-sdk/credential-provider-cognito-identity";

const user = /* get the current authenticated user from Cognito */

// Get AWS credentials from the authenticated user
const cognitoIdentityClient = new CognitoIdentityClient({ region: "MY_REGION" });
const identityId = await cognitoIdentityClient.send(new GetIdCommand({
  IdentityPoolId: "MY_IDENTITY_POOL_ID",
  Logins: {
    'cognito-idp.MY_REGION.amazonaws.com/MY_USER_POOL_ID': user.signInUserSession.idToken.jwtToken
  }
}));
const { Credentials } = await cognitoIdentityClient.send(new GetCredentialsForIdentityCommand({ IdentityId: identityId.IdentityId }));

// Pass these credentials to the ChimeSDKMeetingsClient
const client = new ChimeSDKMeetingsClient({
  region: "MY_REGION",
  credentials: fromCognitoIdentityPool({
    client: cognitoIdentityClient,
    identityPoolId: "MY_IDENTITY_POOL_ID",
    logins: { 'cognito-idp.MY_REGION.amazonaws.com/MY_USER_POOL_ID': user.signInUserSession.idToken.jwtToken }
  })
});

// Use the GetMeetingCommand to check if a meeting exists
const input = {
  MeetingId: MY_MEETING_ID,
};
const command = new GetMeetingCommand(input);
try {
  const response = await client.send(command);
  // Meeting exists, proceed with joining the meeting
} catch (error) {
  if (error.name === 'NotFoundException') {
    // Meeting does not exist, show a "The meeting hasn't started yet." message
  } else {
    // Handle other errors
  }
}

Note: Replace "MY_REGION", "MY_IDENTITY_POOL_ID", "MY_USER_POOL_ID", and MY_MEETING_ID with your actual values. Also, replace the /* get the current authenticated user from Cognito */ line with your actual code to get the current authenticated user from Cognito.
